# Install XDEBUG in Catalina OSX

Tags: macos, xdebug, macos-catalina, phpize

I found this page

https://bbqsoftwares.com/blog/xdebug-catalina

that help to install Xdebug in Macosx Catalina, after Apple has changed Xcode installation, the headers of php are in another location. But I cannot save phpize file due to readonly permissions and so I cannot change the headers file location.
And so I cannot make the Xdebug.so.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution : 
[Solution for Mac Catalina and Xcode 11][1]https://profilingviewer.com/installing-xdebug-on-catalina.html#build

Answer (score 0):

As per my new finding, you should be able to get it running by using [this portion of the guide](https://bbqsoftwares.com/blog/xdebug-catalina#enabled-support-in-php):

Move the executable somewhere safe. I use `/usr/local/php/extensions`.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/php/extensions
sudo cp $(php-config --extension-dir)/xdebug.so /usr/local/php/extensions
```

Then we edit the PHP configuration to enable Xdebug. Simply edit `php.ini`:

```
sudo nano /etc/php.ini
```

And we add the following at the bottom :

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/local/php/extensions/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```